# Can I bypass the Google Verification on my Huawei Mate 8?

Tags: usb, security, factory-reset, usb-on-the-go

I just bought a Huawei Mate 8 and I can't set it up due to the Google account verification in the setup process. I've messaged the seller asking for the account details but he doesn't know. I don't have an OTG cable or USB and I need a way to get past this so I can do a full reset of the phone. Please help! (This is different to the other questions as the factory reset option still leaves me with the same problem with FRP and I can't use ADB because I can't enable USB debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every phone can do factory reset while turned off, try this:

1. Turn off the Mate.
2. Press and hold at the same time: Volume Up + Home button + Power button, until you see Huawei logo.
3. Then select from Recovery Mode menu “wipe data / factory reset” using Volume buttons to navigate and Power button to confirm.
4. Select “Yes — delete all user data” to confirm the whole operation.
5. After that select option “reboot system now”.

Comment: And be happy after the reboot when the question pops up to provide credentials of the original account. The general procedure for a factory-reset is one thing, Ivo, but that new "protection" causes trouble for many.

Comment: Yeah I've done that a few times already but the Factory Reset Protection is still enabled and I can't find anyway to disable it.